# How do I get a list of all AVAILABLE packages from the repositories that are configured from a command line?

Tags: package-management, official-repositories

OK, I understand how to get a list of installed packages on my system.  Now how can I get a list of all available packages from the list of repositories configured?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want an up-to-date list of the available packages, first update the `apt` cache:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then in a `Terminal`, you can run:

```
apt-cache dump
```

But this will print a lot of informations about each package version, repository and dependencies; so the output might be tweaked a bit based on need: for example if you just want a list of names in alphabetical order, you can run:

```
apt-cache dump | grep -oP 'Package: \K.*' | sort -n
```